# Why does printing a char* give a string rather than an address?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I'm going through the basics of learning C++, but keep hitting a wall when trying to decipher the following about chars and pointers. Included are line comments giving my current understanding of what's going on. Given that I have code like below:

```
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
          //String literal is an array of chars
          //Array address gets assigned to a ptr of char
          char myletters[] = {'h','i'};
          char* lp = myletters;
          cout << *lp << endl;

          //Logically equivalent to above statements
          char* letters2 = "hi";
          cout << *letters2 << endl;

          //String literal turns into array of chars
          //Array of chars gets assigned to a ptr of chars 
          //Each ptr of chars gets stored into letters array
          char* letters[] = {"hi","hello"};
          cout << *letters << endl;   
    }
```

My output will be:

```
h
h
hi
```

My question is: when I use the final cout to print the contents of *letters, why do I get the string "hi" rather than the address of "hi" or the address of the first character in "hi"? I get that the first uses of cout are printing a char, and that the last cout is printing a char*, but I'm still wondering why it prints the complete string rather than the address as I would generally expect from a pointer.

Thanks kindly.

Comment: There's a special overload for the `operator<<()` with `char*`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You should make that an answer because that *is* the answer.

Comment: All string functions work on string pointers.  If you need a memory location cast the pointer to a long __(long)stringPtr__

Comment: @ArifBurhan - cast it to `void*`. There's no guarantee that `long` is big enough to hold an address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `<<` operator has a special definition for `char*` that prints the C-string it refers.

In your case, `*letters` has `char*` type (being letters a `char*[]`, same  as `char**`) and not `char` as `*lp` have.

Comment: I would add that to print the adress, you just have to cast to a `void*` so that the overload for `const char *` is not used anymore: `cout << static_cast<void*>(*letters) << endl;`